# Im trying to connect a BI Connector Instance on Docker to my DB in Mongo Atlas

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-biconnector

I'm trying different ways to connect to Mongo Atlas but it haven't been possible. I may be forgetting something but the documentation is no very detailed. Maybe I need to pay to have that feature?
Currently this is my mongosqld.conf file:

```
systemLog:
  path: '/logs/mongosqld.log'
  verbosity: 10
mongodb:
  net:
    uri: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.abcde.mongodb.net:27017/?replicaSet=atlas-24535-shard-0&ssl=true&w=majority&retryWrites=true'
    auth:
      username: "user"
      password: "password"
      mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1"
      source: "dbName"
net:
  bindIp: localhost
  port: 3307

security:
  enabled: true
```

And I keep getting this error:

`SCHEMA     [manager] error initializing schema: unable to execute command: server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0-shard-00-02.abcde.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided }, ] }`

Any clue or can you point me in the right direction?

My BI Connector version is 2.14.3 and is dockerized.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes I was able to fix it. Are you using mongo atlas ?

Comment: yes, I am using mongo atlas, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Enable SSL and it will work

```
  net:
    uri: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.abcde.mongodb.net:27017/?replicaSet=atlas-24535-shard-0&ssl=true&w=majority&retryWrites=true' # https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-uri
    ssl:
      enabled: true
```